# Multiple shopify Rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, shopify

I have a Rails server doing multiple things and I want to create there two clients for two Shopify apps, but I haven't been able to find how to do this.

The omniauth.rb is like this:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :shopify, ENV['SHOPIFY_API_KEY'], ENV['SHOPIFY_SHARED_SECRET'],
            :scope => 'read_themes, write_themes, read_script_tags, write_script_tags',
            :setup => lambda { |env| params = Rack::Utils.parse_query(env['QUERY_STRING'])
                env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_options][:site] = "https://#{params['shop']}" }
end
```

And then, the apps would have different callback links, so in the routes.rb I have this:

```
    get '/auth/shopify/callback', to: 'plugins/shopify#callback'
    get '/auth/shopify/callback_single_app', to: 'plugins/shopify#callback_single_app'
```

and in the shopify_controller.rb this:

```
class Plugins::ShopifyController < ActionController::Base
    include GsMixpanel
    include Ga

    def callback
        puts "In the callback"
        redirect_to "/1"
    end

    def callback_single_app
        puts "In the callback single app"
        redirect_to "/2"
    end
end
```

And I have configured in each of the apps different callback links (one to callback and the other one callback_single_app).

So, what are the problems:

1 - I can only catch one of the apps because I can only define one API_KEY.

2 - The app that has the callback link called callback_single_app doesn't go there.

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are trying to cram two Apps into one instance of Rails? If you cannot stomach making an App with its own instance, maybe the mountable engine concept will bail you out? Seems like more trouble than it is worth though.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply.
I must confess that I may not have understood your answer completely. What do you mean by "mountable engine concept"?
And what's your suggestion for having two apps in Shopify? I mean, do you think there should be two instances of Rails running for this? It seems to me not to be a good solution.

Again, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: From what I've seen, the best solution might be to add a new provider (OmniAuth::Strategy). Do you think this is a good solution?

Comment: Rails Apps are cheap. One session for N Apps is asking for beats to the head. If you pull it off, brilliant! Engines are a Rails concept everyone should know by now. Nothing new there.

Comment: Sorry, David. I still don't understand how you think I should solve this problem. What's your suggestion? :)

Comment: I have nothing more to add. You are on your own dude. Have fun.

Comment: That was not really helpful. But ok, thanks anyways.

Comment: My point is this... ONE APP is ONE RAILS instance, specific to that App. You can connect thousands of shops to this one App on a single Rails instance. 

If you have TWO APPS, you should create TWO Rails instances, one for each App, because these Apps are different. Then you can connect thousands of shops to each App. You can connect the same shop to both Apps, and they will function fine.